# Android log in and waiting screen

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication

I was developing an app log in page, and was trying to add a waiting page using an activity in dialog style, just like the picture. So, in the logging-in code, I set up a thread for connecting to network and validating the account, also set up a thread for starting the waiting page. But, if it validated successfully, how can the app destroy the waiting page and enter the main function activity? If it failed, how can the app destroy the waiting page and return to the log-in page?

[image]

Comment: probably more of a problem where you need to run a trigger for you wait page that detects an (alert of some sort) on your other page that has one alert for the successful logging in, and one for the failed login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a progress dialog for this purpose. If you are using Async Task then declare a dialog as:

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

And display it in "onPreExecute" procedure as:

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Login",
                    "Please wait for a while.", true);
```

And, in "onPostExecute" procedure close the dialog after loggin in as:

```
progressDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Thank you! I have tried in this way and it works. But if I want to realize it with an activity, are there good solutions?